# Kotlin long primary constructor and inheritance

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa

This question could be generalized, but it crept up while creating a Kotlin `@Entity` class within the Spring Data framework. Each entity shall extend `AbstractPersistable`, and it usually has quite a number of fields:

```
@Entity
class Book(
        var author: String? = null,
        var title: String? = null
): AbstractPersistable<Int>()
```

Now this snippet shows a tiny table. You can easily imagine more fields (columns), and usually each field has a comment, a `@Column` or `@OneToMany` annotation, and then blank lines between them. It soon will fill a page. That’s not the bad thing (in my opinion).

What bugs me with that code is that the super-class (or any implemented interfaces) get separated from the `class Book` line so much – it becomes hidden. This happens whenever you use Kotlin’s primary constructor feature. It’s great in general, but moves the focus of class definition from inheritance to data.

What are the stylistic options?

1. Get used to it. New language, new patterns.
2. Do not use this syntax. Use the `constructor` keyword instead. Mirrors what Java would look like. However, to use the class as before, you have to swallow a bitter pill: Create the constructor by hand, including not only all the assigments, but ideally also all the default values for all the fields as well, basically duplicating the code.
3. The third perfect way that I cannot think of at the moment.

Comment: [This blog](https://kotlinexpertise.com/hibernate-with-kotlin-spring-boot/) seems to give an answer by *The equals/hashCode dilemma: Don't use data classes as Hibernate entities*, but for an additional reason. So for now, you may want to choose your 2. stylistic option.

Comment: The question is a bit broad, so help me here. How would you'd like it to look, say in some perfect future language?

Comment: @deHaar: This question is not about data classes. I know said blog article, and while the author chose _not_ to implement Spring Data’s `Persistable`, his approach looks very much similar to what I have written: Fields first, super-class at the end.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin: All other languages that I’ve used put the super-classes/interfaces first, before the attributes of the class. Ideally, I would like to keep it that way (just like in Java, C++, you name it), but keep the cool feature of the primary constructor, as Kotlin has it.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding the closest you could get to what you're looking for is this:

```
class Book private constructor(): AbstractPersistable<Int>() {
    constructor(
        author: String? = null,
        title: String? = null
    ) : this()
}
```

Basically making the primary constructor private, and forcing to use secondary constructor.

I would like to point this part:

> "this moves the focus of class definition from inheritance to data"

That is actually one of Kotlin intentions, have more composition over inheritance. Same goes for how they built `by` into the language.